# Close Parent Tab after closing of child tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

```
 ====================Apex Class Code========================
Public Boolean isClosed{get;set;}
isClosed = false;
List<Opportunity> Affre_main = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity opp: [select id,Afree_main_sol__c from Opportunity where Id in: oppVar] ){
        opp.Afree_main_sol__c = 'some value';
        Affre_main.add(opp)
}
if(!Affre_main.isEmpty()){
    insert Affre_main;
    isClosed = true;
}

========================ON VF Page=================================================
<script>
if("{!isClosed}"){
    window.close();
    //Now how to close its parent tab//
}

</script>
```

I am looking for a workaround. I want to close a tab (say child tab) and then I want to auto-close the parent (main tab).

Is there any standard way then please tell me.

I want to use this solution with visualforce-salesforce.

Javascript/jquery solutions will also be helpful.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .Attempt a solution yourself first and then post the code you are having issues with. There is many ways to do it and without your code the questions is subjective to opinion and personal preferences which is not a question for SO.

Comment: wait I am sending the code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with the code you wrote and not to write code for you.

Comment: @guradio I am not asking you to write the code for me or anyone.If you don't wanna help then its ok and let other do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it myself.

just a quick line solution.

Just need to use  `window.opener.close();` to auto close the parent window from the open child window.